# PHP check every string separately in a foreach loop if it is equal

Tags: php, html

I would like to make my table more viewable. My table will be created from a database. And it's simple like:

```
Test1 | Test2 ...
---------------
Yes   | No    ...
Yes   | Yes   ...
No    | Yes   ...
Yes   | No    ...
```

And I want that all Yes'es are green and all No's are red.

The entries of the table will be created by a foreach loop.

I have an example but I used array instead because it's easier to show the problem. But I think it's the same principle. (I only tested the first row)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$contacts = array('N', 'J', 'N', 'N', 'J');
$demo_str = 'J';
?>

<table style="border-radius: 10px; overflow: hidden; background: #fff; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #dfdfdf;" class="shadow">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 180px;">Test1</td>
            <td style="width: 105px;">Test2</td>
            <td style="width: 100px;">Test3</td>
            <td style="width: 80px; ">Test4</td>
            <td style="width: 80px; ">Test5</td>
            <td style="width: 98px; ">Test6</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php  if ($demo_str == $contact) {
      echo "<html>
<head>
     <style>
     .redifnull1 {
         color: green;
     }
    </style>
</head>
</html>";
  }
  else {
      echo "<html>
<head>
     <style>
     .redifnull1 {
         color: red;
     }
    </style>
</head>
</html>";
  };
     ?><strong class="redifnull1"><?=$contact['test1']?></strong></td>
                <td><?=$contact['test2']?></td>
                <td><?=$contact['test3']?></td>
                <td><?=$contact['test4']?></td>
                <td><?=$contact['test5']?></td>
                <td><?=$contact['test6']?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

And the problem is, that it only compare with "$contacts = array('N', 'J', 'N', 'N', --->'J'<---);", so with the last "letter" and everything is green, if the last one is "N" everything is red.

Does anyone knows how a can solve this problem?
Thank you very much,

best

Edit (how I'm fetching from database):

```
// Connect to MySQL database
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();

$page = isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

$records_per_page = 8;


$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY date LIMIT :current_page, :record_per_page');
$stmt->bindValue(':current_page', ($page-1)*$records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':record_per_page', $records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$contacts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$num_contacts = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts')->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating different `<style>` blocks doesn't work like this. All the styles in the page are merged, and the last style for a selector takes precedence.

You also can't have multiple `<html>` and `<head>` tags in a document. You're creating new ones each time through the loop.

Instead, create a single style block that defines two classes, `redifnull` and `greenifnull`. Then use the appropriate class in your table rows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .rediffnull {
        
        color: red;
    }

    .greenifnull {
        color: green;
    }
</head>
<body>

<?php
$contacts = array('N', 'J', 'N', 'N', 'J');
$demo_str = 'J';
?>

<table style="border-radius: 10px; overflow: hidden; background: #fff; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #dfdfdf;" class="shadow">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 180px;">Test1</td>
            <td style="width: 105px;">Test2</td>
            <td style="width: 100px;">Test3</td>
            <td style="width: 80px; ">Test4</td>
            <td style="width: 80px; ">Test5</td>
            <td style="width: 98px; ">Test6</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <td><strong class="<?= ($contact == $demo_str) ? "greenifnull" : "redifnull" ?>"><?=$contact['test1']?></strong></td>
                <td><?=$contact['test2']?></td>
                <td><?=$contact['test3']?></td>
                <td><?=$contact['test4']?></td>
                <td><?=$contact['test5']?></td>
                <td><?=$contact['test6']?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi I have a question. Your solution worked fine in my php editor, but I tried it with my database and it didn't work. My texts which are YES and NO where saved via varchar(255) - Of course I adapted the J to YES

Do you have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Without seeing how you're fetching the database values and using it in this code it's hard to say.

Comment: `$contact` is an associative array, you need to compare the appropriate column. So `$contact == $demo_str` should be `$contact['column'] == $demo_str`

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `COUNT(*)` query. You can just use `$num_contacts = count($contacts)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.green { color: green; }
.red { color: red; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$contacts = array('N', 'J', 'N', 'N', 'J');
$demo_str = 'J';
?>

<table style="border-radius: 10px; overflow: hidden; background: #fff; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #dfdfdf;" class="shadow">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 180px;">Test1</td>
            <td style="width: 105px;">Test2</td>
            <td style="width: 100px;">Test3</td>
            <td style="width: 80px; ">Test4</td>
            <td style="width: 80px; ">Test5</td>
            <td style="width: 98px; ">Test6</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong class="<?= $contact === 'J' ? 'green' : 'red'; ?>"><?=$contact['test1']?></strong>
            </td>
            <td><?=$contact['test2']?></td>
            <td><?=$contact['test3']?></td>
            <td><?=$contact['test4']?></td>
            <td><?=$contact['test5']?></td>
            <td><?=$contact['test6']?></td>
       </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to approach issues in a manner where I later can add more styles to be flexible for the future:

```
<?php
    $contacts = array('N', 'J', 'N', 'N', 'J');
    $contact_styles = [
        'J' => 'rediffnull',
        'N' => 'greenifnull',
    ];
?>
```

In this way you can just do this:

```
<td>
     <strong class="<?=$contact_styles[$contact[0]]?>"><?=$contact[0]?></strong> 
</td>
```